# Need help returning correct url after using CreateView

Tags: python, django, url

I am having difficulty returning the correct URL after submitting my form. I can get it to work by directing it to the index page, however I would like it to direct to the newly created project url. for example I want the url to look like this:

www.example.com/username/project-slug

I have been trying for about 5 hours now with no luck :-(. Any help would be much appreciated!

views

```
class CreateProject(CreateView):
    model = UserProject
    form_class = UserProjectForm
    template_name = 'howdidu/create_project.html'
    #success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(CreateProject, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('index')
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register_profile/$', views.register_profile, name='register_profile'),
        url(r'^update_profile/$', views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
        url(r'^create_project/$', views.CreateProject.as_view(), name='create_project'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page, name='user_profile'),
        url(r'^(?P<project_title_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
        )
```

models

```
class UserProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_overview = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    project_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='project_images', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True) #should this be unique or not?

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(UserProject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

project urls

```
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('howdidu.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/', include('howdidu.urls')), #do i need this?
```

Comment: Where is the URL definition for:  www.example.com/username/project-slug ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `get_success_url`

```
def get_success_url(self):
    username = self.kwargs.get('username', None)
    project_slug = self.kwargs.get('project_title_slug', None)
    return reverse('user_project', kwargs={
        'username': username,
        'project_title_slug': project_slug
    })
```

`user_project` is the name of the url, but i don't know if that's the one you need to match.
Change whatever you need to match the example with your urls definition

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried what you said but both the username and project_slug return none? How can I rectify that?